# Is 'for starters' formal or informal?

Tags: formality

What is the formality level of the phrase "for starters"?

Can I use it in formal letters?

Comment: It really depends on context. I can think of instances where I would find it too informal to suit my purposes, but also places where I think it would be fine, even in a business letter.

Comment: I see.. Could you give some examples? :)

Comment: To me I think it would be more informal. In a formal setting, I would use *To begin with...*

Comment: @Fokos: Actually, [that's your job](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439). (It would be easier to leave an answer if more details were provided in the question.)

Comment: You are right. I will elaborate more in my next questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED defines the relevant usage as...

> **starter** 3a. phrase
>    ***as*** or **for a starter, for starters** - to begin with, for a start.
>    colloquial (orig. U.S.)

That sense was first recorded in 1873, but I'd say it's still a colloquial/informal usage today - as is this specialised "sub-sense" first recorded 1966...

> 3b *A dish eaten as the first course of a meal, before the main course (also in plural). **colloquial***

---

Regardless of the "first use" dates above, I suspect many native speakers today (particularly, BrE) are like me, in that they would see OP's usage as a "metaphoric" reference to *[entrée](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entr%C3%A9e)/first course of a meal.*

Comment: Being in the States, I equated it with "for beginners", although in context I can certainly see it as fitting into either situation you mention (although we tend to think of the first course as an appetizer, not an entrée, and as Wikipedia just taught me, the usage of entrée to refer to a main course is unheard of outside North America!).

Comment: @Samuel Lijin: No, unless you're in a *very* contrived context, the usage has nothing to do with *starters = beginners* (by implication, *learners* who haven't been learning long enough to know very much yet).

Comment: "For starters" is more like "to begin with". Oh...which I belatedly notice is actually in the cited definition. Anyway, I think I've heard "for beginners" used in that same sense--although that is definitely a very colloquial vulgarism.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Does the metaphoric connotation still applies for "openers"?

Comment: @Pacerier: See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+starters+I%2Cfor+openers+I%2Cfor+starters+it%2Cfor+openers+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20starters%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20openers%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20starters%20it%3B%2Cc0) showing that this use of ***for openers*** has negligible currency compared to ***for starters*** (and it's almost exclusively a relatively recent AmE usage, *very* rare in BrE)...

Comment: ... But even though I rarely hear it and would *never* use it myself, I can't really stop myself from understanding ***for openers*** as a metaphoric reference to ***cricketing*** rather than the first dish in a substantial meal. Also note that (to my mind, at least), such metaphoric use of ***for starters / for openers*** is very much more "slangy" than the much more common ***for a start*** (and I think *nobody* would normally say ***for an opener*** with this sense - but since I'm not American, I can't swear to that).

Comment: Definition 4b from [the full OED...](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131708?redirectedFrom=openers#eid) **opener** - *b. colloquial. **for** (also **as**) **openers**: to start with, ‘**for starters**’.*